# how to use pywinauto to get checkbox in treeview

Tags: treeview, pywinauto

some UI list  like this have some button or check box in treeview

```
|    | GroupBox - ''    (L807, T366, R1257, B746)
|    | ['GroupBox']
|    | 
|    | TreeView - ''    (L815, T382, R1249, B732)
|    | ['TreeView']
|    | child_window(auto_id="1176", control_type="Tree")
|    |    | 
|    |    | CheckBox - 'Intrusion Prevention'    (L839, T384, R957, B402)
|    |    | ['CheckBox', 'Intrusion PreventionCheckBox', 'Intrusion Prevention', 'CheckBox0', 'CheckBox1']
|    |    | child_window(title="Intrusion Prevention", control_type="CheckBox")
|    |    | 
|    |    | CheckBox - 'USB Malware Protection'    (L874, T402, R1010, B420)
|    |    | ['USB Malware ProtectionCheckBox', 'CheckBox2', 'USB Malware Protection']
|    |    | child_window(title="USB Malware Protection", control_type="CheckBox")
|    |    | 
|    |    | TreeItem - 'Network Virus Protection'    (L858, T420, R996, B438)
|    |    | ['Network Virus Protection', 'Network Virus ProtectionTreeItem', 'TreeItem', 'TreeItem0', 'TreeItem1']
|    |    | child_window(title="Network Virus Protection", control_type="TreeItem")
```

I can use  TreeView to see Treeitems like this

dlg = app.top_window()

a = dlg.TreeView

b = a.print_items()

i can see b have tree item (ex:Network Virus Protection) but no checkbox (ex:Intrusion Prevention) so how can i get checkbox ele from treeview?

i know can use child_window("title") to get check box , but i need get this ele and check it text, so use title are not better

Answer (score 0):

you can try this extension,
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ClickCorp.clicknium
it includes one automation library, and can recorde the checkbox and do check or uncheck operation：

```
ui(locator.notepad.checkbox).check()
```